# Problem with AutoMapper version 10.1.1 Cannot create an instance of type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

I am using AutoMapper version 10.1.1 with custom converters for my models. I have extension method where I pass in IMapperConfigurationExpression.

```
public static partial class AutoMapperConfigurator
    {
        public static void ConfigureAutoMapper(IMapperConfigurationExpression config)
        {
            config.CreateMap<SourceModel, DestinationModel>().ConvertUsing<SourceModelTypeConverter>();
            config.CreateMap<DestinationModel, SourceModel>().ConvertUsing<DestinationModelTypeConverter>();
        }
    }
```

I am registering this in ServiceCollection like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AutoMapperConfigurator.ConfigureAutoMapper);
```

When I run the code and inject IMapper inside my Controller where I try to map from SourceModel To DestinationModel i get following error:

AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type Fortitude.Web.AutoMapperConfigurator+SourceModelTypeConverter

I want to use custom converters because they are cleaner way where I have the whole mapping in one file instead of creating profiles.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

I tried along side this line:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AutoMapperConfigurator.ConfigureAutoMapper);
```

add this one:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

and now code works, but I don't want to use this second line if not needed. Shouldn't first line be enough?

Comment: Can someone expain to me why I am getting minuses on both my questions? Why did I do wrong? Or someone is just hitting it with no reason?

Comment: Instead, you should migrate your `AutoMapperConfigurator` to the profile class which implements `Profile`. Then register the profile class. Actually, it is unnecessary to create multiple profiles, you can group those mapping rules into a single profile class/file.